# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I got a problem when i want make a dependent dropdown in Ajax Using Codeigniter. 
I want make a sub-dropdown but when i make code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    /*Get the satuan_kerja list */

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('Pendaftaran/get_satker');?>",
        data:{id:$(this).val()}, 
        beforeSend :function(){
      $('.satuan_kerja').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        },                         
        success: function (data) {
          /*get response as json */
           $('.satuan_kerja').find("option:eq(0)").html("Pilih Satuan Kerja");
          var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          $(obj).each(function()
          {
           var option = $('<option />');
           option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);           
           $('.satuan_kerja').append(option);
         });  

          /*ends */

        }
      });



    /*Get the unit_kerja list */


    $('.satuan_kerja').change(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('pendaftaran/get_unit_kerja');?>",
        data:{id:$(this).val()}, 
        beforeSend :function(){
      $(".unit_kerja option:gt(0)").remove(); 
      $('.unit_kerja').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");

        },                         
        success: function (data) {
          /*get response as json */
           $('.unit_kerja').find("option:eq(0)").html("Pilih Unit Kerja");
          var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          $(obj).each(function()
          {
           var option = $('<option />');
           option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);           
           $('.unit_kerja').append(option);
         });  

          /*ends */

        }
      });
    });

  });

</script>
```

First function is work but when i choose or select the first form or dropdown it must be show sub-dropdown, but the second function for subdropdown doesn't work and i got error like this :

```
>Uncaught SyntaxError: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
at Object.success (daftar:365)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
 at y (jquery.min.js:4)
  at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

> this is a code for pendaftaran/get_satker and pendaftaran/get_unit_kerja

```
Public function get_satker()
        {
            $query=$this->db->get('satuan_kerja');
            $result= $query->result();
            $data=array();
            foreach($result as $r)
            {
                $data['value']=$r->id_satker;
                $data['label']=$r->nama_satuan_kerja;
                $json[]=$data;


            }
            echo json_encode($json);

        }


Public function get_unit_kerja()
        {

              $result=$this->db->where('id_satker',$_POST['id_unit_kerja'])
                            ->get('unit_kerja')
                            ->result();

            $data=array();
            foreach($result as $r)
            {
                $data['value']=$r->id_unit_kerja;
                $data['label']=$r->nama_unit_kerja;
                $json[]=$data;


            }
            echo json_encode($json);

        }
```

Comment: There is a error in your JSON, that's about all I can tell you right now. The JSON is the problem, please provide it.

Comment: the "JSON" is probably being sent as HTML

Comment: If you provide us the url of site_url('Pendaftaran/get_satker');  please

Comment: check your browsers **developer** tools network page to see what your server is sending in the response - most likely a HTML response, or perhaps XML - without knowing a thing about your server side, there's no possibility of getting more specific guidance - most likely there's something wrong with your `pandafarten/get_unit_kerja` page, or how you are trying to request it

Comment: @RobertI oke i already provide it.

Comment: @JaromandaX i add pandafarten/get_unit_kerja on question, so you can see it.